# Display a Text in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2019, blazor, webassembly

I try to make a project in Visual Studio 2019 (Blazor Webassembly), the project is like when i insert a text and choose a specific time (it can be different any time) and at last choose the date then show me that text as i wrote.

For example here in the pic 2 i insert Some Text in the text area and choose 07:10 as time and the date of today, consider now is 07:08 the message should display two minutes later.

Thank you in advance.

[Pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwbtT.jpg)

[Pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LKE9.jpg)

[Pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/miN0D.jpg)

Comment: Do you want the text to appear next time user opens this page?  For example, you enter this for tomorrow, user closes the browser, and the text appears the next day when the user opens the web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You posted a question without any code, so I'll answer without code too.

- In your HandleValidSubmit() method, store the message somewhere, like in a `SortedList<DateTime, string>`
- Make sure the next-up item is always easily available , in _next.
- in override OnInitialized(), create a System.Timers.Timer. An interval of  1 - 30 seconds seems appropriate.
- in the Elapsed event:

  - `if (_next.Key <= DateTime.Now)  // showtime`

    - update the UI elements
    - update _next
    - call  `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);`